# Node+Express pipe file directly to writeStream

Tags: node.js, express, stream, fs

In terms of learning i need to make a file uploading by myself with `fs.streams`

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
  req.pipe(fs.createWritableStream('files/file.png'))
    .on('error', (err) => next(err))
    .on('close', () => {
      res.json({image: 'files/file.png'});
    })
})
```

This is dosen't work. So two questions

- How to get file name and data from req?
- How to connect this two streams?

---

Update: In all tutorials described opposite action - read file from `fs` and `pipe` it to `res` to enduser.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `multer`

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
  dest: 'folderName'
});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('formField'), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({image: req.file.path});
})
```

in this code file path will be sent.
if you want to send file itself, then you should write:

```
res.download(req.file.path);
```

instead of `res.json({image: req.file.path})`.

I don't know how `res.download` works exactly. maybe it takes whole buffer of the file and sends it.

multer's documentation is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)